# Html webpack plugin html file not generated

Tags: reactjs, plugins, webpack

I just started with webpack, and I want to automatically generate index.html file using html-webpack-plugin.

My webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            hash: true
        })
    ]
}
```

[image]

I execute "npm run dev" equals to webpack --mode development, and only 1 file generated "main.js".

I don't see any html files, could you please help me?

webpack: 4.5.0
html-webpack-plugin: 3.2.0

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue

You just need to specify path in output, because HtmlWebpackPlugin is looking for path

```
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the entry

```
entry: {
  main: [
    './src/'
  ]
},
```